# Access VBA update a column to concatenate

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, concatenation

I was trying to update a column from a table in my Access database with following VBA code but it did not work as nothing happpened to that column. I would like to concatenate 5 columns into one. This update statement would work in SQL server but obviously not here.

```
currentdb.Execute "update sys_AAAA_AAAA set ABI=AAT+AAU+AAV+AAW+AAX"
```

Any advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps some fields are *Null*?

Try using the string "concatenator" preferred by Access, *ampersand*:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "update sys_AAAA_AAAA set ABI = AAT & AAU & AAV & AAW & AAX"
```